# Turn PS/2 keyboard Caps Lock LED on/off in custom kernel

Tags: c, assembly, keyboard, kernel

I'm developing a kernel with assembly language and C and in the boot up process, I want the kernel to turn the [Caps Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_Lock) key on and then off. I have found the reference for the LED on the key [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/PS2_Keyboard#Commands). How could I call that function with C or assembly ([NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) style)?

Comment: Your own OS? What platform (HW)?

Comment: Have you tried writing the command byte to port 64h and the data byte to port 60h ?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Got it....

Answer (score 1):

```
SetKeyBoardLeds:
   push  eax
   mov   al,0xed
   out   60h,al
KeyBoardWait:
   in    al,64h
   test  al,10b
   jne   KeyBoardWait
   mov   al,byte [keyBoardStatus]
   and   al,111b
   out   60h,al
   pop   eax
   ret
```

For example,

```
   mov   [keyBoardStatus],0xb0    ; Initialise keyboard LED state
   call  SetKeyBoardLeds
;--------------------------------- This will toggle CapsLock LED
   xor   [keyBoardStatus],4
   call  SetKeyBoardLeds
;---------------------------------
   and   [keyBoardStatus],0xfb
   call  SetKeyBoardLeds
```

where keyBoardStatus is a byte (it will hold the current keyboard LED state).

Answer (score 0):

You can read [my code](https://github.com/danghai/Kernel/blob/master/irq_handler/irq_ex2.c) for reference:

*irq_ex2.c*: An interrupt handler example. This code binds itself to IRQ 1, which is the IRQ of the keyboard controlled under Intel architectures. Then, when it receives a keyboard interrupt, it reads the information about the status LED and keycode into the work queue.

Pressing:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd> → Caps Lock LED OFF
- <kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd> → Caps Lock ON